# Statistical Method for Normalization of Data

Tags: anova, normalization, descriptive-statistics, psychometrics

I collected data using a pre-test instrument to capture baseline emotions (two dimensions: valence and arousal) of participants. The two dimensions in the questionnaire range from calm to excited (arousal), and pleasure to displeasure (valence).After the test, I employed a different tool to measure the emotional responses of the participants.

Now, to ensure standardization across, I am required to normalize the data (from the dimensions in both questionnaires). Can you please advise how to normalize the data collected in the two instruments.

It will not be conceivable to use the data gathered in the posttest because not everyone who came into the lab had the same state of emotion.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some background as to what you  mean by needing to "ensure standardization across" and being "required to normalize the data" (and why you feel it is necessary). If you primarily want to analyse the data after the test taking into account different pretest conditions, then it is not clear to me why you would have to do those things.

Comment: The reason the data need to be normalized is because not every participant who arrives in the lab are in the same emotional state. Normalization, as I understand will standardize the data, ready for analysis to obtain consistent result. For instance if participant A was excited during pre-test, and after performing the test, he became frustrated. Participant B was calm during pre-test, and after the treatment, he was uneasy.

Comment: Are we supposed to convert the data into log form??